# Add Text inside Rectangle using Skia Sharp with wrap lines

Tags: c#, image-processing, skiasharp

I want to draw Text inside skia Rectangle.
If text is large then it should be draw in next line
And want to create method in which i will pass text color, font size , font name ,X & Y coordinates for rectangle already rendered.

So text should be inside Rectangle also text should be in specific aligned (Left,Center, Right) specified in method parameter

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code to check? For now, please read [StringFormat Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: I dont want to use system.Drawing. i am using SkiaSharp library

Comment: Then check [SKCanvas.DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skcanvas.drawtext?view=skiasharp-1.68.0)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as of this message, SkiaSharp does not have a really good story when it comes to drawing text. It has all the required bits to draw even the most advanced cases, but exposes them in a really advanced (basically useless for the common man) way.

Until we can get a decent story with all the toys, I would strongly suggest having a look at this library which does more than you can possibly imagine:
https://github.com/toptensoftware/RichTextKit

[image: RichTextKit]

Comment: hello Matthew maybe you could advise if you have change with my issue regarding text kit? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448518/placing-each-sentence-on-new-line-with-richtext